# CSS 100% width layout with two panels - why it doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, layout, liquid

I'm sure there are lot of simillar questions about 100% layouts, but first I couldn't find one with this exact issue and second I want to know why is this happening.

I'm trying to create a liquid layout with divs and CSS. I am totally free to use CSS3 advantages and most importantly, I want it to be as clear as it can get.

I started by creating wrapper, inside it a 100px height header. Then I did a 250px width navigation (I tried also 25%, but the result is same) and a footer with 50px height. All other dimensions are 100% or using the CSS3 calc(100% - 150px) function. Problem is that the elements bellow header doesn't even show in the viewport. With little experimenting, I got the elements shown, but with problems like content div displayed bellow everything else (instead of aside left panel) or footer sticked in the middle of a page when it overflowed (absolute positioned), so none of them worked and they were all pretty dirty.

I tried floats, various dimensions, wrapping columns with another div, but still, I can't find a solution.

Here's my code

HTML:

```
<header id="head"></header>
<div id="over">

    <nav id="side-nav"></nav>

    <div id="content"></div>

</div>
<footer id="main-foot"></footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: white;
}

#over {
    height: auto;
    min-height: calc(100% - 150px);
}

#head {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
        background-color: #D1C5C5;
}

#side-nav {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #AFAFC9;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    background-color: #AFC9B0;
}

#main-foot {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

The code above is result of some experimenting, so there can be faults that I overlooked, but I tried every common solution.

I have a solution with some absolute positioning and I'm sure I can find bunch of other complicated ones, but I am really interested why this one doesn't work.

Is there someone who has deeper understanding willing to help?

PS: I don't need to support non-CSS3 browsers like IE6, 7, 8 and others...

Comment: I built a fiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/dcL8K/

Comment: i tried your exact code in jsfiddle with firefox, it seems to work ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify your css for `#over` :

```
#over {
    height: 100%; /* Instead of auto */
    min-height: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

That should solve your problem.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhLJs/)

`height : auto` sets the height as the height of its content, i.e its child elements.
`height : 100%` inherits the height of its parent.

So, here, `#over` calculates the height of `#side-nav` and `#content` which in-turn depend on the height of `#over`.

And since, `#side-nav` and `#content` don't have any content, so the height for all is `0`.

So, this problem should be rectified as content builds up. One more solution would be to set `min-height` for `#side-nav` and `#content` with some `px` value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! I feel pretty dump that i haven't noticed that, but it works! (for this particular layout i needed to set height:  calc(100%-150px);, since the header and footer are outside the container div.) Many thanks!